# SetContentView parameter is showing error

Tags: java, android

I am trying this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

main is my `main.xml` in my menu folder , but its showing me error in `activity_main`

error

`Activity not resolved or is not a field`

Same for

```
mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.opencv_part_java_surface_view);
```

and

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

above showing error on `R.menu.main`

Comment: if main is `main.xml` then use `setContentView(R.layout.main);` instead of `activity_mai`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have imported `android.R.java` where it should be `yourpackage.R.java`.

If you did that then delete the `import android.R` and then clean and build your project.